# <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,358.76643475…

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to read csv from local host and draw the line with d3.js, but it seems like it didn't work with it. I am a freshman in js, so I don't know how to trace the error. It seems like I can't translate csv file value into float. Hope someone help me thanks.

```js
d3.csv("data.csv")
  .row(function(d) {
    return {
      timestamp: parseDate(d.timestamp),
      value: Number(d.value)
    };
  })
  .get(function(error, rows) {
    max = d3.max(rows, function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
    minDate = d3.min(rows, function(d) {
      return d.timestamp;
    });
    maxDate = d3.max(rows, function(d) {
      return d.timestamp;
    });


    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, max])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([minDate, maxDate])
      .range([0, width]);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.timestamp);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      })
      .curve(d3.curveCardinal);


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("id", "svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");
    var chartGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class", "chartGroup").attr("transform", "translate(" + xNudge + "," + yNudge + ")");

    chartGroup.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(rows);
      })


    chartGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    chartGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis y")
      .call(yAxis);



  });
```

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10-12 | 296.0423862136376 |
| 2020-10-13 | 1346.6782154772111 |
| 2020-10-14 | 1787.0539770632580 |
| 2020-10-15 | 1369.5196008434164 |
| 2020-10-16 | 1489.2648598800539 |
| 2020-10-17 | 1745.4144145032478 |
| 2020-10-18 | 1745.1782130630731 |
| 2020-10-19 | 1745.0470333079959 |
| 2020-10-20 | 1610.2533436870555 |
| 2020-10-21 | 1566.3546004777141 |
| 2020-10-22 | 967.6859477362229 |
| 2020-10-23 | 292.0932016835135 |
| 2020-10-24 | 0 |
| 2020-10-25 | 0 |
| 2020-10-26 | 0 |

Comment: I made you a snippet without line numbers. Please update it to a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it

Comment: `Number(d.value)` will only be `NaN` when `d.value === undefined` -> [21.1.1.1 `Number ( value)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) -> [7.1.3 `ToNumeric ( value )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric) -> [7.1.4 `ToNumber ( argument )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)

Comment: If you want to make an example without an external file, you can do `d3.csvParse(\`"timestamp","value"
"2020-10-12","296.0423862136376"
"2020-10-13","1346.6782154772111"
"2020-10-14","1787.0539770632580"
"2020-10-15","1369.5196008434164"
"2020-10-16","1489.2648598800539"
"2020-10-17","1745.4144145032478"
"2020-10-18","1745.1782130630731"
"2020-10-19","1745.0470333079959"
"2020-10-20","1610.2533436870555"
"2020-10-21","1566.3546004777141"
"2020-10-22","967.6859477362229"
"2020-10-23","292.0932016835135"
"2020-10-24","0"
"2020-10-25","0"
"2020-10-26","0"
\`)`